# Xorg Server refusing to start after Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid upgrade

Tags: upgrade, xorg, fglrx

Hellu.

Yesterday evening I decided to upgrade my laptop (14.04) to the latest release, aka 15.04. I ran "do-release-upgrade" as root, said yes to everything and went to bed. This did not go as smooth as I had planned thought.

Today when I woke up and were going to try the new release I was met with ... nothing. Basically a black-screen.
When the laptop boots up it first says is:

```
Starting version 219
```

Afterwards the standard Ubuntu screen comes up. When it have finally loaded the computer ends up displaying nothing what-so-ever and goes into  what I like to call "fire mode" (cpu on full, fan on full, feels like the pc is going to melt). No error messages or anything is printed after this point.

I recently also discovered that pressing CTRL+ALT+1 gives you a terminal where I can login. I tried typing "startx" but it the Xorg server failed to start. I checked the log file and it seemed like it missed the package "fglrx". I do not longer have this log file as Ubuntu overwrote it on reboot and I forgot to make a copy of it.

My logical conclusion was then to install this "fglrx" package. This seemed to fix my previous error however now a new appeared.

**Logs**

My current Xorg generated log file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11495951/

My syslog contains these lines:

```
Jun  1 13:56:47 maxubuntu failsafeXServer[1232]: xinit: giving up
Jun  1 13:56:47 maxubuntu failsafeXServer[1232]: xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
Jun  1 13:56:47 maxubuntu failsafeXServer[1232]: xinit: server error
```

I have a **AMD Radeon HD 6620g** graphic card if that helps...

I dont know what more logs I can/should provide? Any solution on this would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Comment: try http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/194128/116970

Comment: @solsTiCe your link worked but it did not fix it. In the end I reinstalled my computer and it appears to have fixed it...